# How to fix Qt QMainWindow's Draggable Area Issue with QToolBar in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgraphicsscene, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I'm facing a strange issue when trying to add a `QMainWindow` to a `QGraphicsScene`. For all intents and purposes, please do not recommend me to use the `QMdiArea` as the alternative, because that distracts away from the actual issue I am having and it does not fit my needs.

Here is the minimal example that exemplifies 2 key issues, both of which I believe to possibly be Qt bugs.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent){
    resize(1000, 750);

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView;
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    view->setFixedSize(1000, 750);
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->scene()->setSceneRect(-150, -150, view->size().width(), view->size().height());

    setCentralWidget(view);

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
    widget->resize(300, 300);
    QVBoxLayout* vLay = new QVBoxLayout;

    widget->setLayout(vLay);

    QMainWindow* testWindow = new QMainWindow;
    testWindow->resize(300, 300);

    QToolBar* toolbar = new QToolBar;
    toolbar->setFloatable(false);
    toolbar->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red"); //For better seeing the issue
    toolbar->addAction("Test");

    testWindow->addToolBar(toolbar);
    vLay->addWidget(testWindow);

    scene->addWidget(widget);
}
```

Now, you may be scratching your head and wondering why the heck I'm even doing this...

tl;dr: I'm creating a custom mdi area within the `QGraphicsView` with a custom Dock and layering manager. I need each subwindow to have a dockable `QToolBar`, much like a `QMainWindow`, but only the `QMainWindow` supports this feature out of the box. Each subwindow is the overarching `QWidget` in my example above.

Before converting the "inside" contents of my subwindow to a `QMainWindow`, everything was working fine, and even as a `QMainWindow`, everything is still fine. However, once I add the `QToolBar` to the `QMainWindow` everything begins to go wrong.

You will notice upon start up that the program looks correct and that the `QToolBar` is correctly placed and offset. Now if you try to drag the `QToolBar` anywhere at all, even outside of the `QMainWindow` and perform a mouse key release, one of two things will happen:

1. The program will crash and have a very strange stack trace while running on my current system: Qt 5.10.1 with gcc 5.2.0 on REHL
2. The `QToolBar` will incorrectly snap to the wrong location within the `QMainWindow`. Look closely at the predefined rectangular area when dragging and hovering over a valid dockable location and use the red border as a guide.

The crashes are inconsistent and sometimes happen every second drag event after the first. Sometimes it happens the moment you grab the `QToolBar` and other times it happens after the drop event. I'd add the stack trace, but every single time the debugger has a different output. I have seen some messages regarding nVidia.so libraries such as these:

```
7fd6d96c1000-7fd6daf36000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 34442271                   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.390.67
7fd6daf36000-7fd6db135000 ---p 01875000 fd:00 34442271                   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.390.67
7fd6db135000-7fd6db4a9000 rw-p 01874000 fd:00 34442271                   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.390.67
7fd6db4a9000-7fd6db4c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd6db4c2000-7fd6db5d3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 35871194                   /usr/lib64/libGLX_nvidia.so.390.67
7fd6db5d3000-7fd6db7d3000 ---p 00111000 fd:00 35871194                   /usr/lib64/libGLX_nvidia.so.390.67
7fd6db7d3000-7fd6db7f8000 rw-p 00111000 fd:00 35871194                   /usr/lib64/libGLX_nvidia.so.390.67
7fd6db7f8000-7fd6db7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd6db7ff000-7fd6db800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd6db800000-7fd6dc000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:30187]
7fd6dc000000-7fd6dc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd6dc021000-7fd6e0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd6e00aa000-7fd6e00ad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3060689                    /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.390.67
7fd6e00ad000-7fd6e02ad000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 3060689                    /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.390.67
7fd6e02ad000-7fd6e02ae000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 3060689                    /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.390.67
```

The debugger may have over 50 greyed-out function callbacks, sometimes the same, sometimes different. Notably I've seen the `QPropertyAnimation` mixed in those callbacks, but not every time, so I can't pinpoint it and I feel like I'm going mad.

Now, you might think that this has to do with the `QMainWindow` being embedded as a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` within the `QGraphicsScene` and just having a side effect from that... but no. If you instead add just the `QMainWindow` to the scene directly and bypass using the `QWidget` that contained it, then everything works fine. Snapping works with no offset issues and there are no more crashes. Due to this interaction I'm almost convinced it is a Qt bug and would like to submit a bug report using this post as a base. If I'm missing something or need to update my graphics drivers, I will. However, it doesn't explain why the snapping does not match the `QMainWindow's` rubber band rectangle placement when you're dragging.

Comment: That is supposed to be a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this strange issue is analogous to my other post regarding context menus inside of a `QGraphicsScene`. To fix this behavior, simply set the `setWindowFlags(Qt::BypassGraphicsProxyWidget)` on either the parent window widget or the sub-mainwindow itself. If you do it on the parent widget, it'll implicitly apply it to the `QMainWindow`. Anytime there seems to be an issue in a `QGraphicsScene`, setting that above flag seems to solve most bugs/issues.